# n-type mosfet calculate AD AS PD PS

Tags: mosfet, nmos

I have a nMOS and I want to calculate AD AS PD PS .
Given: L=0.25μm and W = 2μm.
We know that \$AD = W*L_D\$ and \$PD = W + 2*L_D\$

```
.MODEL NMOS NMOS (                                  LEVEL  = 3                  
+ TOX    = 5.7E-9          NSUB   = 1E17            GAMMA  = 0.4317311          
+ PHI    = 0.7             VTO    = 0.4238252       DELTA  = 0                  
+ UO     = 425.6466519     ETA    = 0               THETA  = 0.1754054          
+ KP     = 2.501048E-4     VMAX   = 8.287851E4      KAPPA  = 0.1686779          
+ RSH    = 4.062439E-3     NFS    = 1E12            TPG    = 1                  
+ XJ     = 3E-7            LD     = 3.162278E-11    WD     = 1.232881E-8        
+ CGDO   = 6.2E-10         CGSO   = 6.2E-10         CGBO   = 1E-10              
+ CJ     = 1.81211E-3      PB     = 0.5             MJ     = 0.3282553          
+ CJSW   = 5.341337E-10    MJSW   = 0.5             )
```

my problem is how to found \$L_D\$ the length of drain and source ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the geometry of the transistor. You need to look at the actual layout of the device to get these parameters. If you haven't done a layout yet you can use the design rules to get a good estimate.

Using the design rules, the minimum length of a drain/source region might be the sum of:

1. the minimum space from a contact to the gate poly
2. the minimum size of a contact
3. the minimum overlap of a source/drain diffusion around a contact

Comment: is there a way from my given data to find L_D ? for example what are LD and WD parameters

Comment: No, you have provided a SPICE model file that can be used with transistors having just about any geometry. The LD and WD parameters model lateral diffusion of the active regions under that gate...they are much too small to be the parameters you are looking for.